# Get height of the element which is hidden in other element using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a offcanvas menu (it has `display: none` by default).

Inside that menu I have my element (`display: block`) and I want to get the height of this element on page load.

`var myElementHeight = $(myElement).outerHeight();`

Of course above code returns `0`.

Chrome Developer Tools:

Menu closed:

[image]

Menu opened:

[image]

One idea comes to my mind: clone this element, append to HTML, hide using visibility property and get the height of this element, but I think it is too tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.element').show();
    _height = $('.element').height();
    $('.element').hide();
  });
```

Use a loading gif icon if it needs to.